# NotSerializableException: RemoteThreadsListenerTestElement with JMeter 5 on JDK 8

Tags: java-8, jmeter

I'm running JMeter 5.0 with OpenJDK8 but there is an error when I try to run it on Master-Slave mode. The Slave is started using

```
./jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<slave_ip>
```

and the Master is started using

```
./jmeter -n -t /home/user/test.jmx -R <slave_ip>
```

and I get the following error on Master machine:

```
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /home/user/test.jmx
Configuring remote engine: <slave_ip>
Starting remote engines
Starting the test @ Tue Nov 06 10:34:00 EST 2018 (1541518440058)
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerTestElement
Remote engines have been started
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
```

Test script `test.jmx` is just a GET to google.com, not using any third-party plugins.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and JMeter was obtained on JMeter's website.

Has someone experience this problem and solved it?

Note: I saw some posts related to this but they are outdated **and** the solutions didn't work.

**Edit 1**:
Both Slave and Master are using version 5.0 r18409351. I also tried running both on 1 host and I've got the same error.

**Edit 2**:
Looking at jmeter.log, I noticed it was trying to connect to localhost, even though I had `remote_host=<slave_ip>` on `jmeter.properties`. I added 
`-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<slave_ip>` to Master's command line. Now I get the following exception on `jmeter.log`

```
2018-11-06 16:20:12,963 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=<slave_ip>
2018-11-06 16:20:12,965 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2018-11-06 16:20:12,967 ERROR o.a.j.e.ConvertListeners: RemoteException occurred while replacing Remotable item.
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 0; nested exception is: 
        java.io.IOException: Could not bind to /<slave_ip> using port 0
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:254) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:236) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:383) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:346) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(UnicastRemoteObject.java:225) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteSampleListenerImpl.<init>(RemoteSampleListenerImpl.java:44) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ConvertListeners.addNode(ConvertListeners.java:78) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
        at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976) [jorphan.jar:5.0 r1840935]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.runTest(ClientJMeterEngine.java:135) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.start(DistributedRunner.java:132) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
```

[JMeter Script](https://gist.github.com/luizfzs/81b9cecd4c294202d9b57705c11f549b)

Comment: Does slave have the same exact jmeter version?

Comment: @user7294900 It does, both have version 5.0 r1840935. Also I tried running both on the same host and I had the same problem.

Comment: Can you share your test plan ? I tried with a simple test plan and distributed test and I do not reproduce so there must be some condition. Also provide the jmeter.log and jmeter-server.log . Thanks

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK updated the question

Comment: Thanks but your link is broken , I get a 404

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK fixed. sorry. that was a typo

Comment: I updated my answer. For now I cannot test with same version of Java. But jmeter's travis runs with openjdk

Answer (score 0):

First check you are using same version of Java for client and server.

Using your test plan it works for me with Oracle JDK 8u161:

To run server with IP **192.168.0.33**:

> ./jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.0.33 -Dserver_port=5000 -s -j jmeter-server.log

On client:

> ./jmeter -n -t /data/jmeter/testplan.jmx -R192.168.0.33:5000

Comment: Yes, they are both the same version

Comment: I ran `./jmeter -n -t /data/jmeter/testplan.jmx -R<slave_ip>:1099` but I still got `Could not bind to /<slave_ip> using port 0`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you send to wrong port, this is [configurable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#portchange) so call IP with port as

```
 remote_host=<slave_ip>:1099
```

> By default, JMeter uses the standard RMI port 1099.
>
> On the client, update the remote_hosts property to include the new remote host:port settings